# Developing a comprehensive set of SQL statements/queries based on Sakila or other standard database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, db2, teradata

I'm developing a comprehensive set of `SQL` statements/queries based on `Sakila` or other standard database.

I'm testing a number of DB Connectivity Drivers, against different DBs (i.e. `MySQL`, `Oracle`, `MSSQL`, `DB2`, `Teradata`, and many other). I need to validate the drivers on as many SQL statements/queries as possible.

Note (thanks @wumpz for the right comment):
The drivers do not just send the statements directly to the DB, but the statements go through a heavy parsing, and many other things happen, before the statement gets to the DB. Hence, I need to validate the whole processing chain and on as many SQL statement variations as possible.
Also, I need to validate the data returned from the DB - that's why it's based on a standard DB *including* test data, such as Sakila.

The set should be very-very large - 100s or 1000s of statements.

The set should be diverse:

- `SELECT` statements
- `UPDATE` statements
- `INSERT` statements
- `DELETE` statements
- etc. etc. etc.

The statements should range from basic to very complex:

- including `JOIN` clauses
- including nested statements
- including sub-queries
- including `WITH` statements
- etc.

Please, suggest sources of information on existing test sets, that could help my work.

Thanks ahead for your help!

---

List of suggested sources of information:

- [TPC (transaction processing and database benchmarks)](http://www.tpc.org/)
- [JSQLParser (great SQL parser technology - includes a comprehensive test set)](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser/tree/master/src/test/resources/net/sf/jsqlparser/test)
- [StackOverflow Sakila questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sakila+query)

Comment: If you can test only one statement, lets say a simple select, it means the driver works. You dont need to use every possible SQL Statement in a SQL Engine to validate the driver.

Comment: Not exatly: I have to validate it works on ALL the SQL standard.

Comment: There are the TPC benchmarks with queries (including different syntax dialects), see http://www.tpc.org

Comment: Don't try to invent the wheel all over again, just read the documentation for the drivers you are using.

Comment: @where_ That assumes that a connectivity driver always parses the statements. That is not true. Statements can be sent directly to the database, therefore the simple select sql test would be enough.

Comment: @wumpz, you're right. I should've mentioned that the drivers do not just send the statements directly to the DB, but they go through a heavy parsing, and many other things happen, before the statement gets to the DB. So, I need to validate the whole processing chain.

Comment: @wumpz, BTW, thanks alot for the JSQLParser. Great technology!

Comment: @dnoeth, thanks for the hint - I'm checking the http://www.tpc.org/.

Comment: I reworded the question. My intention is to develop the test set and contribute to the Open Source Community. Please, reopen the question, as it calls for a real discussion of something that is, indeed, missing in the Comunity right now!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a comment or worth an answer.

**JSqlParser** (https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser) uses a set of nearly **300 Oracle** specific sqls.

You find it in the test sources at:
https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser/tree/master/src/test/resources/net/sf/jsqlparser/test/oracle-tests

Comment: yeah, I will definitely use those queries for validation.

Comment: However, what I'm looking for, ultimately, is a statement/query set based on Sakila or other comprehensive standard (with test data included). Because, I need to validate the whole chain, starting with parsing, and upto getting the results from running the statement on the DB.

Comment: again, thanks alot for the JSQLParser. Great technology!

Comment: I guess, when I acquire such a test set - I will be very glad to keep developing it further and contribute it to JSQLParser.

Comment: That would be great ...